# Role, Users and Permission Admin Tool

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, spring-security, security

I might be wrong in my assumption, but it seems to me that many of the basic and even complex RBAC based mechanisems will end up needing a UI to create users, assign users to roles and assign permission to roles. And all this should be stored in some sort of backing structures (file system or Database tables).

An example of a similar ERD is shown at:
[Spring Security Example ERD](http://springinpractice.com/2010/10/27/quick-tip-spring-security-role-based-authorization-and-permissions/)

Bottom line question, is there any Java based Web application that provides the supporting UI for this setup?

Even if the whole thing is not out-of the-box, any framework that gives some starting point for such UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such tool exists.
Not sure why, but if anyone is working by the basic example of User--roles--permission ER, they would still have to develop their own UI to maintain this.

Sure there are frameworks (as pointed out by Rob) to assist in creating this UI very fast.

Answer (score 1):

[AppFuse 2](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) provides a great jump start on a creating a webapp using Spring MVC, JSF, Struts 2, Tapestry, Wicket or Stripes. Using the [Quick start guide](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart), you will be up and running an application within a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question, yes there are some ready to use frameworks, where you don't need to create or develop UI, because itself provides UI to create users, manage users, manage roles, manage permissions, etc.